# Will I lose all my data if I upgrade my hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm wanting to change my hard drive to a bigger one, but I'm unsure what will happen to all my saves and achievements.

The cloud isn't big enough for all my saves and that so I'm wondering if I recover my gamertag will everything go to my new hard drive?

Answer (score 9):

When you recover your gamertag, it will recover all of your achievements since those are bound to your gamertag. However, you will have to buy another storage device (such as a USB drive, see steps below), or a [transfer cable](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/set-up-transfer-cable) to move all of your old saves/other data to the new hard drive.

> USB device
>
> 1. Copy all data such as saves to the USB device through the Xbox 360 system / data settings.
> 2. Insert your new hard drive, connect your USB device, and copy your data/saves from the USB device to the new hard drive.

Comment: Cheers letty I though I mite have to do this after reading quite a lot of similar questions on here .. Cheers again